# Error 1292 al actualizar fecha mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, subconsultas

Buenas estoy atorado con un error a la hora de intentar cambiar una fecha en mysql esta en varchar formato mm/dd/yyyy y trate pero errojo el error 1292 a la hora de hacer el update quiero ponerla en YYYY/MM/DD pero en el cambio todo se me pasa a un año en especifico 2019 en todas las fechas trato de actualizarlas pero con update pero primero hice un ensayo con select.

```
select birth_datee,
  case
    when
      birth_datee like "%/%"
    then
      date_format(str_to_date(birth_datee, "%m/%d/%y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
    when
      birth_datee like "%/%"
    then
      date_format(str_to_date(birth_datee,"%m/%d/%y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
    else
      null
   end
as new_date
```

pero cuando uso el update con esa expresion me arroja el error 1292 y si uso

```
SET sql_mode = ''
```

me actualiza las fecha pero con el año mal en todas..

Comment: Es que estás usando la misma condición en ambos casos :)

Answer (score 0):

Primero, el formato que MySQL usa para `DATE` es YYYY-MM-DD (aunque lo suficientemente flexible como para también aceptar YY-MM-DD, YYYYMMDD, YYMMDD, YYYY/MM/DD, etc.). Partiendo de allí, ya que la función `STR_TO_DATE` retorna un valor de tipo `DATE`, no es necesario que luego utilices `DATE_FORMAT` para terminar mostrando la fecha en ese mismo formato en que ya la obtienes (`%Y-%m-%d`).

Segundo, indicas que el formato que usas para las fechas que almacenas como `VARCHAR` es MM/DD/YYYY, lo que significa que no se corresponden en su totalidad con el formato que emplea MySQL.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, con SQL en modo estricto (`SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';` o `SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';`), `STR_TO_DATE('11/14/1984', '%m/%d/%y')`, por ejemplo, siempre generará una advertencia de código 1292 (puedes visualizar estas advertencias ejecutando `SHOW WARNINGS;`). Esta advertencia se convertirá en error (de código 1292) cuando, estando aún en modo estricto, intentes añadir o actualizar valores en tabla (usando `UPDATE` o `INSERT`).

Ahora bien, con `SET sql_mode='';` te deshaces de este error a la hora de insertar o actualizar. No obstante, el error que ahora presentas con el año incorrecto se debe sencillamente al uso de `%y` (nota que está en minúscula) en la función `STR_TO_DATE`. La opción adecuada es `%Y` (nota ahora en mayúscula), justo como lo hiciste luego en la función `DATE_FORMAT`.

`STR_TO_DATE(birth_datee, '%m/%d/%Y')`

La fecha 11/14/1984 convertida a `DATE` usando `STR_TO_DATE` con las opciones `%m/%d/%y`, produciría 2019-11-14 (año 2019), porque `%y` (en minúscula), que captura únicamente dos dígitos para el año, solo está tomando 19 de 1984. En la captura de años usando dos dígitos, los valores correctos son interpretados desde 70 (1970) hasta 69 (2069); 00 representa el año 2000.

Algunos ejemplos usando `%y` y `%Y` para un mismo año:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/14/2356', '%m/%d/%y'); -- 2023-11-14 (año 2023)
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/14/2356', '%m/%d/%Y'); -- 2356-11-14 (año 2356)

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/14/8622', '%m/%d/%y'); -- 1986-11-14 (año 1986)
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/14/8622', '%m/%d/%Y'); -- 8622-11-14 (año 8622)

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/14/5814', '%m/%d/%y'); -- 2058-11-14 (año 2058)
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/14/5814', '%m/%d/%Y'); -- 5814-11-14 (año 5814)

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/14/1999', '%m/%d/%y'); -- 2019-11-14 (año 2019)
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/14/1999', '%m/%d/%Y'); -- 1999-11-14 (año 1999)
```